# Lots of errors when compiling project using FMOD with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, fmod

I decided to use FMOD for sound playback in my project, but I'm getting lots of compiler errors which I am unsure of how to fix.

The header file of the class using FMOD looks more or less like this:

```c
#ifndef PROJECTNAME_SOUNDMANAGER_H_
#define PROJECTNAME_SOUNDMANAGER_H_

#include <iostream>

#include <fmod.h>
#include <fmod.hpp>
#include <fmod_errors.h>

class SoundManager {
    public:
        static SoundManager &instance();
        void play(char *data, size_t size, bool loop=false);
        void stopAll();
    private:
        void ERRCHECK(FMOD_RESULT result);
        SoundManager() : mSystem(nullptr) {
            initFMOD();
        }
        SoundManager(const SoundManager &other);
        SoundManager &operator=(const SoundManager &other);
        void initFMOD();
        FMOD::System *mSystem;
        FMOD::Sound *mSound;
        FMOD::Channel *mSoundChannel;
};

#endif // PROJECTNAME_SOUNDMANAGER_H_
```

And here are some of the compilation errors:

```
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1054:33: error: expected ')' before '*' token
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1056:33: error: expected ')' before '*' token
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1058:33: error: expected ')' before '*' token
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1059:33: error: expected ')' before '*' token
.....
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1465:5: error: 'FMOD_SOUND_PCMREADCALLBACK' does not name a type
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1466:5: error: 'FMOD_SOUND_PCMSETPOSCALLBACK' does not name a type
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1467:5: error: 'FMOD_SOUND_NONBLOCKCALLBACK' does not name a type
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1473:5: error: 'FMOD_FILE_OPENCALLBACK' does not name a type
.....
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1828:19: error: expected initializer before 'FMOD_Memory_GetStats'
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1829:19: error: expected initializer before 'FMOD_Debug_SetLevel'
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1830:19: error: expected initializer before 'FMOD_Debug_GetLevel'
...../api/inc/fmod.h:1831:19: error: expected initializer before 'FMOD_File_SetDiskBusy'
.....
...../api/inc/fmod.hpp:59:21: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
...../api/inc/fmod.hpp:59:51: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'release' with no type [-fpermissive]
...../api/inc/fmod.hpp:62:21: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
...../api/inc/fmod.hpp:62:21: error: declaration of 'FMOD_RESULT FMOD::System::_stdcall'
...../api/inc/fmod.hpp:59:21: error: conflicts with previous declaration 'FMOD_RESULT FMOD::System::_stdcall'
...../api/inc/fmod.hpp:62:73: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'setOutput' with no type [-fpermissive]
...../api/inc/fmod.hpp:63:21: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
...../api/inc/fmod.hpp:63:21: error: declaration of 'FMOD_RESULT FMOD::System::_stdcall'
...../api/inc/fmod.hpp:59:21: error: conflicts with previous declaration 'FMOD_RESULT FMOD::System::_stdcall'
.....
```

If it makes any difference, I'm compiling with `-std=c++0x`.

I've tried searching but I wasn't able to find anything that helps me with these errors.

Please note that I'm using FMOD Ex 4.44.06.

**EDIT:** I seem to have found the problem. When I make a minimal example and compile it without `-std=c++0x`, everything compiles fine. However, if I add that flag, I get the same errors as with this project. Is there no way to make FMOD play nice with C++11?

Comment: What are the *first* errors? C++ errors tend to cascade, and if something went wrong *before* you included this file, there could be many errors as a side effect of the first one. A common culprit is a missing semicolon at the end of a class definition.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry for not being clear about that, the first errors that are printed are the first errors you see in my post above.

Comment: I downloaded 4.44.06 and those line numbers don't agree with my fmod.h at all. 1054 - 1056 is a comment, for instance.

Comment: @molbdnilo Huh, that's strange. I checked fmod.h and the version is defined as 0x00044406 so it's not a remnant of an old installation. Here's my fmod.h: http://pastebin.com/bmCyrtha

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there's something defined as a macro or something not defined as a macro. Now, your task is to provide a minimal example. This can mean manually deleting large pieces of code or copying code from the header files. Do that until you can provide the offending code in a few lines. I guess that doing so, you will find the problem yourself.

There are a few things I noticed with the little code you provided:

- fmod() is actually a function and I could imagine a few compilers providing this as a macro, which in turn conflicts with #include, but that doesn't seem to be your problem.
- You include both fmod.h and fmod.hpp, which looks suspicious.
- `void ERRCHECK(FMOD_RESULT result);` looks like a mix between function and macro.
- `play()` should probably take a `const char* data`.

Comment: I tried making a test file that only included the FMOD headers and nothing else and to my surprise it compiled! However, when I stripped the offending class of all references to FMOD except for the header includes, I still get the same errors. Hmm... I shall investigate further. To address your points, fmod.hpp includes fmod.h, so that isn't a problem. Even if I remove the fmod.h include, I still get the same errors. ERRCHECK is just a function, but I admit that it could have a better name. play() should indeed take a const char*. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under MSYS2 and GCC v5.4.0 I was facing the same problem.
The solution was add the compile flag `-D__CYGWIN32__`.

This is due the following in fmod.h:

```
#if defined(__CYGWIN32__)
    #define F_CDECL __cdecl
    #define F_STDCALL __stdcall
    #define F_DECLSPEC __declspec
    #define F_DLLEXPORT ( dllexport )
#elif defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(_WIN64)
    #define F_CDECL _cdecl
    #define F_STDCALL _stdcall
    #define F_DECLSPEC __declspec
    #define F_DLLEXPORT ( dllexport )
...
```